# A good way to simulate large number of user request to a web service?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, simulation

I have a web service that makes of different tomcat containers. They perform different tasks in the web service system. For example, some of them serve as login services, some serve as registration services, some serve as RESTapi services.

I want to simulate large number of different user requests, say more than 10,000 at the same time, to find out where the bottleneck of the web service is as well as to test the stability of the system.

Is there a good way to simulate that using java? As I know, using java multi-thread has a limited number of threads depending on different JVM or OS. So are there other better ways to simulate those requests?

Comment: search SO/Google for "java load testing"

Comment: @Jonas , do u know how does JMeter simulate those request with java? do they use any data structure like priority queue or something?

Comment: a key factor might be networking - you don't want all your requests going over the same local network link otherwise it's likely to be artificially friendly to your server.  You need to decide how to utilise distributed computers to load your server up across several independent network links.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is better option as per your requirement. You can test your web service performance with that tool.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bw1KnQBZ4LY7aTVLZXRwdlVGSFU) I have attached the video of How to test a web service with JMeter. I  think it will be helpful to you.